# Как сделать скролинг (или Page Up, Page Down) страницы Chrome?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ:** C#, WebDriver, Chrome

Как сделать скролинг страницы?
Или  нажать Page Up, Page Down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).SendKeys(Keys.PageUp);
```

Другими словами просто "прицепляемся" к элементу и от него двигаем страницу